# Prevent back navigation in browser, but not prevent refresh using window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, navigation, alert

I am attempting to alert the user that navigating back will log them out. I found this nice code here on stackoverflow that works well; however, I do not wish to alert the user if they refresh the page. Here is the code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Going back will log you out, and lose your information. Are you sure you want to do this?";
};
```

I've already disabled the backspace button from being used to navigate back. This code alerts the user when they use the navigation back arrow, mouse button, or on page refresh. I want the alert to come up with all except for page refresh.

Comment: Have u checked `Window.onpopstate` event? And for backward compatibility history.js library ?

Comment: Using Window.onpopstate from the example located at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history 
works great for Chrome, but not in Netscape or IE. Haven't tested Firefox yet. I uploaded history.js and tried with that, and the later two browsers give popups three times, which is rather annoying. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwolybug/np8uvL1r/
Also a link to the history.js file for external resource.
http://fossil-bug.com/tmp/history.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onpopstate`:

```
var unsavedData = "Going back will log you out, and lose your information. Are you sure you want to do this?";

window.onpopstate = function askConfirm() {
  if (needToConfirm)
    return unsavedData;
}
```

Comment: needToConfirm condition is OPTIONAL and set to true when an input has been changed:
`$(".prevent_unsaved_data-js :input").on('change', function() { needToConfirm = true; });`